# Kafka Broker may not be available

Tags: apache-kafka, wsl-2

I installed kafka on windows subsystem linux and started using the command `confluent local services start` and all services are up. Now, when I'm trying to run my kafka-spring application from windows, it is showing the following error:- **connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.**

My server.properties are:-

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

Where I'm going wrong???

Comment: What is your /etc/hosts file?

Comment: What is the outcome of command '$confluent local status kafka'

Comment: all services were up, when I tried to check the status using '$confluent local services status'

Comment: Please refer this github link https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the Spring app within WSL2 session such that it's on the same network bridge as the hypervisor